# HTML preview mostrando o primeiro elemento

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Fiz esse html preview, ele funciona muito bem para o meu propósito porém o primeiro elemento está aparecendo como texto, e isso é um mal resultado, eu entendo muito pouco de jquery e javascript, estou começando a estudar, gostaria de entender o que está dando errado.
Se colocar `<div></div>` a tag de abertura aparece: `<div>`, mas apenas a primeira, o resto do código não aparece
Execute o snippet para entender melhor

```js
function showPreview()
{
  var value = $('#copy').val().trim();
  value = value.replace("<", "&lt;");
  value = value.replace(">", "&gt;");
  $('#preview').html(value);
}
```

```css
textarea {
resize:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="copy" onInput="showPreview();"><div><img src='https://i.imgur.com/FfInIT9.jpg' width='100'/></div>
</textarea>
<br>
<div id="preview"/>
```

Comment: Como assim **porém o primeiro elemento está aparecendo como texto**?

Comment: se você coloca `<div></div>` a tag de abertura aparece: `<div>`

Comment: Vc não quer que apareça nenhuma abertura de tag é isto?

Comment: sim, execute o snippet e cole: `<div><div><div>` você vai ver que só a primeira `<div>` aparece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É necessário alterar a function e alterar seu id preview. Assim as tags htmls que digitar irá ser interpretado como tal.

```
function showPreview()
{
 var value = $('#copy').val().trim();
 $('#preview').html(value);
}

<div id="preview"> </div>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: eu tinha tentado assim antes, mas não consegui acho que estava fazendo algo errado, por isso optei pelo `replace` ajudou muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Isto é pq vc está dando **replace**, mas inserindo o caractere de novo, por isso ele mostra o primeiro. Tem que deixar vazio, para que os caracteres não apareçam:

> A expressão regular: `/</g` dentro do replace serve para que toda vez que no texto for encontrado os **<** e **>** sejam substituídos por algo, que no caso aí é nada.

```js
function showPreview()
{
  var value = $('#copy').val().trim();
  value = value.replace(/</g, "");   // vazio
  value = value.replace(/>/g, "");   // vazio
  $('#preview').html(value);
}
```

```css
textarea {
  resize:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="copy" onInput="showPreview();">
</textarea>
<br>
<div id="preview"></div>
```